Anydesk Mac OS. AnyDesk is not connected to the server. Please check your internet connection
I do have connection to the wifi but any desk can't connect to the server. When trying to connect I get the following error message: AnyDesk is not connected to the server. Please check your internet connection. If I click on the circle on the top left which is supposed to be green when connected (Orange in my case), I see the following messages: Negotiating TLS encryption

I've encountered the same issue with AnyDesk. It seems to be a bug where, after closing and reopening the application, it fails to connect to the server and throws the error you mentioned.
Initially, I was resolving this by turning my MacBook off and back on, but this was inefficient since it takes a while to reboot.
A more efficient solution is to reinstall the application. To do this, simply download the AnyDesk.dmg file (the one you used during the initial installation) and double-click it. You will see a screen like this:

Next, double-click the AnyDesk icon, and you'll be prompted with a pop-up that looks like this:

Click 'Reinstall.' This will reinstall the app without affecting any of your previous remote connections, and it should reset the server.

TLDR - this issue was caused by a service outage.
There was one June 27  and another Sep 24, 2024 with similar errors on Mac computers trying to use the service.
In the future if you have this issue, perhaps prioritize working with the vendor and validate there’s not a service issue.
Nothing needed to be changed on the client side to resolve this other than patience and retrying the attempt later.

Since you posted your problem, their servers are not communicating securely - periodically showing invalid for me on their main support page.

Perhaps they have issues with the keys they use or a temporary overload issue on their side. I would reach out to their support to understand if this is related to a service disruption.

https://boot.net.anydesk.com/
https://support.anydesk.org/knowledge/faq
https://status.anydesk.com/

Checking this in 15 minutes or so might be advisable since I just got one good connection out of 10 attempts before posting this answer. They haven’t posted a service alert, but I caught their pages linked above in an unsecured state for the duration since you posted.
It's odd the June 2024 outage no longer shows on their historical page (and that page is relative to now, so you'll have to scroll back more than page 2 soon as time marches on...)
Based on the tests you made and the clear outage, we can conclude in OP's case, their date and internet connection were fine as they were posting here from the affected Mac.
In general - downgrading or upgrading the version of the app while you wait for this negotiation or them to respond to your support case if there is no official communication from support channel when this happens again.

Thank you for your answer. So do I need to wait or try to let them know the issue ?

Do you get an SSL error from either of the above pages? If not you don’t have to wait anymore, restart your Mac and only open a support case if your error persists once the web pages work and your reboot is complete, @JonasGrutter

I had one for the first link but now that I rebooted I don't have it anymore. My problem with any desk still persists though.

We both have issues with their SSL certificates. I would open a case (linking to your question here if you want) and then go make tea or coffee or go for a walk if you don’t need to fix this in the next hour. Something is messed up on their internet or their infrastructure and it’s getting better. When (how long ago) did your error start?

My error started early this morning (around 8 am UTC+2) but now it has been solved. Thank's for your help!

@JonasGrutter to confirm you never could  fix this on your end (other than waiting for vendor to fix their issues), it was all problems with the service server side?

Do not update the current version (8.1.2). Try reinstalling the previous version.

Thanks for this tip - it seems this question has renewed interest. Can you share a screen shot of the error if it's different than posted in the question? From where would someone get a previous version?

Maybe try changing time to your current time zone ! Worked for me.

I did adapt the timezone but it did not change anything for me. It seems that any desk is not getting any connection as I can't even login in the app.

Did you check your firewall settings ?

Yes I disabled my firewall
